# How can I remove duplicated tags (not synonyms)

Tags: support, tags

How can I remove duplicate tag that is not used and is only singular of a similar tag?

I don't think that these tags can be used as synonyms. Consider the following example:

**question** and **questions**

Comment: If the tag is not used, it'll be removed automatically from the system after 24 hours.